# Database: item can have alternatives, how to link in database?

Tags: database, database-design

I have a database where I want to store multiple items, every item would be unique, but they can have alternatives from other makers. So items would have a potential M:M relationship with each other.

For example, item A could have 3 alternatives. If I add item B, the alternative, the link for the alternative item should also be reversed, so that when I search item B, I would find item A as an alternative. When I add item C, it should be added as an alternative for both item A and B, and C should have as it's alternatives item A and B.

How's the best/smartest way to make this relationship between a class of its own kind?

The way I'm thinking is making a table in between called alternatives with a unique ID for each new item, if an alternative is added, then it's linked to that parent ID (alternative ID) and thus no new ID would be made in the alternative table. If it's established only later that this is an alternative, then remove the alternative ID of one of the two and add the item to the other alternative ID.

```
public partial class Item : Entity
{
    public Item()
    {
        Id = GuidComb.GenerateComb();
    }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string MakerRef { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Maker Maker { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Offer> Offers { get; set; }

    //stuck here on the smart way to make the relationship with itself?
}
```

Any advice would be welcome!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion I'm thinking about might be similar to what you proposed, but I'll try to formulate it in database terms.

As far as I understand your requirements, your alternatives relationship will be completely transitive. This means your item set is partitioned in equivalence classes of subsets containing mutually alternative items. (If an item has no alternative yet, the subset consists of this item alone.)

If that's true, then the most elegant and redundancy free way to represent this is to choose one of the items of such as subset as a representative of the entire subset. This is reflected by the following table design:

```
item(id, equivalence_id, other attributes, ...)
```

where `equivalence_id` is a foreign key to the representative. Each item gets born with an equivalence id of null. If it is made equivalent to another item,

- if the item already present has an equivalence id of null, assign the id of this representative to the equivalence it of both items,
- if the item already present has a non-null equivalence id, assign this to the equivalence id of the new item.

Note that this works, in case there are many items in the same equivalence class, no matter which of this items are used to link the new one.

Example:

```
id   equivalence_id   name
1    1                abc
2                     def
3    1                ghi
4    4                jkl
5    4                mno
```

This means abc and ghi are equivalent, as well as jkl and mno, but def isn't yet equivalent to anything. Now if pqr comes along and should become equivalent to abc, it would get equivalence id 1. The effect is the same as making it equivalent to ghi.

To find all items equivalent to a specific one, query

```
select *
from item
where equivalence_id = :my_equivalence_id
```

If some information pertaining to the equivalence class as a whole should be stored, a separate table for the equivalence classes only should be created.